# Trouble pulling button in btn-group to right

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code which displays some buttons:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4360/)

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Toolbar Group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-add-btn">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-delete-btn">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle as-btn-text as-conf-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Configuration <span class="caret"></span>

        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu as-toolbar-dropdown" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-refresh-btn">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pull the "X" to the far right of the group. I have tried `.pull-right`, `float:right` but neither seem to work.

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put the close ("X") button in its own `.button-group` and pull the group to the right:

```
        <!-- previous button location -->
    </div><!-- close the existing group -->
    <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <!-- new button location -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-refresh-btn">X</button>
    </div>
</div><!-- end .btn-toolbar -->
```

[Here's an update](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4362/) to your fiddle.

The advantage to this approach is that you get the correct button rounding based on the `.button-group` rules and you don't need to alter or override existing Bootstrap framework CSS.

Comment: Me either and it seems to do exactly what I want, without altering the CSS... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updated HTML

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div id ="b"class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Toolbar Group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-add-btn">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-delete-btn">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle as-btn-text as-conf-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Configuration
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu as-toolbar-dropdown" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        </ul>

        <button type="button" id="right" class="btn btn-default as-btn-text as-refresh-btn">X</button>
             </div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
#b{
    width:100%;   
}
#right{
    float:right;
}
```

Working Example:http://jsfiddle.net/tmurmvnx/

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 4 you can use the **`strong text`** class, check this simple example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg float-right" role="group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">
   Btn 1
   </button>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
   Btn 2
   </button>
</div>
```

For more information check this documentation:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with `strong text` class? I can't find a reference to it anywhere in your code and also couldn't find it anywhere in the linked docs.